# Typing behavior of generic methods in Java

Tags: java, generics, runtime, type-erasure, generic-method

I am trying to understand the difference between static and non-static generic methods in Java:

```
public class Pair<K, V> {

private K key;
private V value;


//the type of the _this_ object and the argument should be the same (just like in scompare)?    
public <X, Y> boolean compare(Pair<X, Y> p2) {
    return key.equals(key) && value.equals(value);
}



public static <N, M> boolean scompare(Pair<N, M> v1, Pair<N, M> v2) {
    return v1.key.equals(v2.key) && v1.value.equals(v2.value);

}
}
```

Other than the fact that scompare is static, the behavior should not be different. What I find strange is the following:

```
Pair<Integer, String> p1 = new Pair<>(1, "apple");
Pair<Integer, Integer> e1 = new Pair<>(4, 3);


//causes compile-time error (as it should)    
System.out.println("e1 scompare p1: " + Pair.scompare(e1, p1));

//no compile-time error --- why?
System.out.println("e1 compare p1: " + e1.compare(p1));
```

The compile-time error is that one argument is of type `Pair<Integer,Integer>` and the other is of type `Pair<Integer,String>`.

So my question is: why does `e1.compare(p1)` not cause a compile-time error?

Files for this MWE:

Pair.java: https://pastebin.com/rmY9M0gk

D1.java: https://pastebin.com/1MpvPXBC

[Platform:
`javac 1.8.0_151`
`openjdk version "1.8.0_151"`]

Answer (score 3):

```
public <X, Y> boolean compare(Pair<X, Y> p2) {
    return key.equals(key) && value.equals(value);
}
```

should be

```
public boolean compare(Pair<K, V> p2) {
    return key.equals(key) && value.equals(value);
}
```

...if you want it to fail to compile.  As it stands, your `compare` method is written to accept any `Pair` at all.

Comment: And the name of the method could use some polishing too.

Comment: Ah yes, I get it now. In the case of `e1`, both type parameters `K` & `V`  get the argument `Integer`. This leaves `X`, `Y` to be bound to any reference type at all, resulting in any `Pair` being legal. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In instance method you compare **this** Pair object which is of types K,V
 with another Pair object of types X, Y.

So, it is fine: you have `Pair<Integer, String> p1` (K=Integer, V=String) and you call to compare with `Pair<Integer, Integer> e1` (X=Integer, Y=Integer)

But for **static** method there are no K and V types. You defined only N and M
 and explicitly defined that both parameters must be N,M types. And you do not have it since for p1 N=Integer and M=String while for e1 N=Integer and M=Integer.

To make generic **static** method to compare Pair objects of any classes you have to define all types for both parameters: as

```
public static <N, M,P,T> boolean scompare(Pair<N, M> v1, Pair<P, T> v2)
```

BTW: `key.equals(key) && value.equals(value);` -this does not make any sense.
Did you mean `key.equals(p2.key) && value.equals(p2.value);` ?

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. And you're also right about the expression in the return statement.